# Ender Dragon spawn egg?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that in a previous version of Minecraft, you could get a Ender Dragon spawn egg (a white egg, like it has no texture). Is that still possible, and if how do i get it?

Comment: I don't believe the newer versions have it anymore, but you may be able to obtain it by using console commands.

Comment: If you still want to spawn in the Ender Dragon, just type in this command: /summon EnderDragon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### There's no Ender Dragon Spawn Egg since 1.2

Reading the page on [Spawn Eggs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_Egg#Ability_to_spawn) on the Wiki, it does not seem possible to get an Ender Dragon Spawn Egg since version 1.2.

Specifically,

> **Any entity not in the list above**, such as paintings, entity blocks, or primed TNT, **cannot be created with spawn eggs**, even if set to the relevant entity ID value by commands. The egg is colored gray (Spawn Null.png) and will only work in version 1.1.

(emphasis mine)

As far as I can tell, the list is identical with the spawn eggs you can get in creative mode. Ender Dragon is not listed, and can not be spawned using spawn eggs.

Answer (score 4):

There is an update now which allows you to spawn it. Just simply use the command

```
/summon EnderDragon
```

That's all. Hope I helped

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.19.3, you can now obtain them with the `/give` command.

Answer (score -2):

You can also type '/give  383 1 63'. It'll give you the white egg with grey spots.
It is avaliable on any version below 1.7.5

Example:
 /give Popcorn98 383 1 63

Comment: Does it actually spawn an Ender Dragon though?